# getFixedT not working as expected in react-i18next

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I am trying to use useTranslation inside a react app, and as well I want to refer to a fixed language. the useTranslation t function changes with the browser as expected, but the fixed language always returns english.

The behaviour is demonstrated in this: [codesandbox app](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fervent-galileo-98k7ks?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2f0zfy0006356hjfgknu7s%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2f0zfy0002356hil0tb93t%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2f0zfy0003356hsstft41i%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2f0zfy0005356h1afmifa2%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clu2f0zfy0002356hil0tb93t%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2f0zfy0002356hil0tb93t%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clu2f0zfy0005356h1afmifa2%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2f0zfy0004356h2uor2daz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2f0zfy0005356h1afmifa2%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clu2f0zfy0004356h2uor2daz%2522%257D%252C%2522clu2f0zfy0003356hsstft41i%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clu2f0zfy0003356hsstft41i%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) In this project I get two fixed t functions "en-US" and "fr". Both return the english translations.

In the codesandbox I used:

```
import { i18n } = useTranslation()
```

then later

```
i18n.getFixedT(lng)
```

I have also used the `i18next.getFixedT(lng)` and it has the same behaviour.

Comment: This works... is it how getFixedT is supposed to work?
`let fixtT;
if (lng != i18next.language) {
  const oldLanguage = i18next.language;
  i18next.changeLanguage(lng).then(() =>{
    fixedT = i18n.getFixedT(lng);
    i18next.changeLanguage(oldLanguage);
  })
  .catch((err: unknown) => {if (err instanceof Error) console.error("Error changing language: " + err.message)});
} else {
  fixtT = i18n.getFixedT(lng);
}`
The first argument to getFixedT seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour. getFixedT does not load the language if it is not loaded. The recommended approach is to add the language in  the init function via tha "preload" property.  However if you do not want to preload all the languages on initialization...

The way to do this seems to be to check whether the language has already been loaded:

```
if (!i18n.hasResourceBundle(lng, "translation")){
    i18n.loadLanguages(lng, (err: unknown) => {
        if (err instanceof Error) {
            console.error("Error loading language: " + err.message)
        } else {
            const newDocT = i18n.getFixedT(lng)
            //.... use newDocT
        }
    })
} else {
    const newDocT = i18n.getFixedT(lng)
    //.... use newDocT
}
```

Or there is a new feature that allows a language to be passed into useTranslation (but this is a Hook and cannot be used inside useEffect or other Hook)

`const { t } = useTranslation('translation', { lng })`

You can read about that in [issue 1637](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/1637)